# Initializing state of a component from another component and get the state value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to the reactnative/js world with the asynchronous mechanisms and I read a lot of similar examples but it is not clear to me. So please find here my questions.

I am trying to create a component (called in the example 'anchor') and update its state (the name parameter) from another component.
I would like to get the attribute state.name value of the 'anchor' component from the parent component.
My issues are the followings:
- the creation of the anchor component seems to not handle the props.name parameter for the component creation
- I do not knwo how to access to the component state parameter value (his.state.name) from the parent component (App in the example)

https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/203556/

The Anchor Component

```
class Anchor extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
           this.state = {
              name : props.name
           }
        this.name = this.state.name;
    }

 /*
    getName(){
       return this.state.name;
    }
 */  
}
```

And the App component:

```
class App extends React.Component <any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       anchor : undefined,
       items: [
           { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
           { text: "Learn React", done: false },
           { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
           { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
       ]
     }
 }

addAnchor(){
    var anchor = new Anchor('hello');
    this.setState({
        anchor : anchor,
    });
    console.debug('get my anchor name: '+ this.state.anchor.name);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Todos:</h2>
                {this.state.anchor.name}
            <ol>
                {this.state.items.map(item => (
                <li key={item.id}>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" disabled readOnly checked={item.done} /> 
                    <span className={item.done ? "done" : ""}>{item.text}</span>
                </label>
                </li>
                ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    )}
}
```

Comment: do not initialize state with props.

Comment: I tried also using an other function to update the state (calling SetState) but it does not work.

Comment: pass the parent state as a prop.... then pass another prop.... a function. heres an example..... `<Anchor name={this.state.name} changeName={newName => this.setState({name: newName})} />`

inside anchor use thise like this.... `this.props.name` to access the name , and `this.props.changeName("example")` to change name to example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to ***manipulate Components like some simple POJO***.

Well then try this:

```js
class Anchor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Name: {this.props.name}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'Hello',
      items: [
        { text: 'Learn JavaScript', done: false },
        { text: 'Learn React', done: false },
        { text: 'Play around in JSFiddle', done: true },
        { text: 'Build something awesome', done: true }
      ]
    };
  }
  addAnchor(){
     const anchor = React.createElement('Anchor', { name: this.state.name }, '');
     console.log(anchor.props.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos:</h2>
        <Anchor name={this.state.name} />
        <ol>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" disabled readOnly checked={item.done} />
                <span className={item.done ? 'done' : ''}>{item.text}</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

We have to instantiate a React component in the React's way:

```
React.createElement('Anchor', { name: this.state.name }, ''); // <~~ like this

//var anchor = new Anchor('hello'); <~~ not like this
```

For more detail, you could read it here: [React Without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Hopefully, that helps!

Comment: I will give it a try. In my project, I have some specific algorithm which do not require any render or HTML representation. Indeed, for this I would like to manipulate Components like some simple POJO. Is there a way to do this outside the render ?

Comment: thks but the createElement will create a object element which is not related to my Anchor component. With this solution, I am not able to call some methods from my original Anchor component, for instance: anchor.getName()  ?

Comment: Oh, I see now! Then why don't you just create a normal Javascript class?

Comment: You put the point on the right solution ! I was not sure about using simple Javascript class with React Native as there is no documentation on this (I assumed that only components...). Well it works !